# Packaging CRM Analytics Templates that have a dashboard that uses LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, einstein-analytics, 2gp, tableau-crm, crm-analytics

Is it possible to package a CRM Analytics Template that has a dashboard that uses LWC?

I'm trying to create a 2GP extension package that has a CRMA Template and Lightning Web Components but I'm getting the following error:

```
Version create.... Create version status: Error
Error (1): Multiple errors occurred:
(1) Template_Api_Name: Lightning component does not exist: markup://orgnamespace:crmaSidebarDates
(2) crmaSidebarDates: No MODULE named markup://orgnamespace:crmaSidebarDates found
```

The package version is created correctly if I delete all the references to the LWC in the dashboard. But when I try to create another version where the LWCs are referenced in the dashboard again, the aforementioned error pops up again.

This is my LWC:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>crmaSidebarDates</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>analytics__Dashboard</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="analytics__Dashboard">
            <hasStep>true</hasStep>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-align_center slds-text-color_inverse">{formattedDate}</div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { formatDate } from 'c/crmaUtils';

export default class CrmaSidebarDates extends LightningElement {
    @api results;

    /**
     * @name formattedDate
     * @description returns the query's date formatted in the logged-in user's timezone
     *
     * @returns {String} formatted date
     */
    get formattedDate() {
        let row = this.results[0];
        return `(${formatDate(row.CreatedDate)})`;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm referencing it in the template's dashboard JSON:

```
 "component_6": {
                "parameters": {
                    "attributes": {},
                    "source": {
                        "name": "crmaSidebarDates",
                        "namespace": "orgnamespace",
                        "type": "lightningcomponent"
                    },
                    "step": "Text_Right_Sid_1"
                },
                "type": "component"
            },
```

sfdx-project.json:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "src/sfdc/base/",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "src/sfdc/base",
      "package": "XXX",
      "versionName": "...",
      "versionNumber": "1.5.0.NEXT",
      "postInstallScript": "PostInstallScript",
      "ancestorId": "XXX",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "path": "src/sfdc/extensions/crm-analytics",
      "package": "XXX for Analytics",
      "versionName": "...",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": false,
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "XXX",
          "versionNumber": "1.5.0.LATEST"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "XXX",
  "namespace": "orgnamespace",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "58.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "XXX": "XXX",
    "XXX for Analytics": "XXX"
  }
}
```